# Unsure what the integer for NumPy datatypes represent

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

I was playing with NumPy array datatypes and when I entered this code:

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.array(("Bernie","Bill","Bob"))
print(arr[0].dtype)
```

it outputed:

```
<U6
```

I understand that "U" stands for unicode string but im confused on what the "6" represents.

Comment: Please read the docs. They are pretty clear about stuff like this.

Comment: Python strings can differ in length, but in an numpy array, all strings are stored with the same number of characters (with some sort of null padding as needed).  Here `np.array` determined it needed 6 char, the longest word.  Don't worry if you see longer lengths.  Sometimes too short can result in undesirable truncation.

Answer (score 1):

The 6 represents the number of characters in the string. In this case, 'Bernie' has 6 characters.

Here's another example:

```
print(arr[1].dtype)
>>> <U4
```

In this case `arr[1]` checks the string at index #1, which is 'Bill'.

You may find the following link helpful: [Numpy Docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have set the array(arr) as index of zero. Index zero meaning first string or integer in the list/tuple etc(in your case string in a list), hence 'Bernie' is outputted. The '6' after U (which represents a string) is the amount of characters in the string outputted.